# Error print function python "INVALID: Syntax"

Tags: python

Hello I have an error with the code below.  I am trying to print "Bus num: "busnum. busnum is data taken from a excel sheet. Can someone explain to me why this invalid syntax as well as ways to improve to that part of the code?

```
   for busnum,change in busses_in_year[location]:
   print('Bus #: 'busnum)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you wanted to use string formatting. See below:

```
for busnum,change in busses_in_year[location]:
    print('Bus #: %d' % busnum)
```

Or you could simply do `print("Bus #:" + str(busnum))"`

Either way you can't just stick it onto the end there. You have to add it or format it in.

Answer (score 0):

### ***Or you can just use 'comma'.***

> `print('Bus #: ', busnum)`

Instead of

```
print('Bus #: 'busnum)
```